# Validation the string using Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, regex

I'm trying to validate the string is matching the certain format. If it fails it should throw error.
I'm trying check whether the given string is matching the required format.
I have a array, I'm checking array content is present in the string and checking it can accept only {or}, {and}.

Example:-
var arrayList = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
I have a array containing a,b,c,d,e.   so the Input should be in the format of
var Input = "a{or}b{and}c{and}d{or}e".so Input should be of this kind format (i.e i can put {or},{and} between the contents present in the array).
I have achieved till here. but i should also be allow to accept '(', ')' character between them. i.e (a{or}b{and}){or}(c{and}d{or}e).
How can i make the regex to allow '(' , ')' between the existing Input string

Can anyone Please let me know how can i achieve it.

```js
     
function validateInput(){
       let InLevelTableList = ['tab1', '33', 'list'];
     let InlevelParentLogic = "(tab1{and}list){and}33"
    try{
      if(InLevelTableList.length > 1){
            console.log(InLevelTableList)
            let regex = '';
            let arrayVar = '';
            for (let ind = 0; ind < InLevelTableList.length; ind ++) {
              if (ind === InLevelTableList.length-1) {
                arrayVar = arrayVar + InLevelTableList[ind] + ')\\b';
              } else if (ind === 0) {
                arrayVar = '\\b('+InLevelTableList[ind] +'|';
              } else {
                arrayVar = arrayVar + InLevelTableList[ind] +'|';
              }
            }
            for (let ind = 0; ind < InLevelTableList.length; ind ++) {
              if (ind === InLevelTableList.length-1) {
                regex = regex + arrayVar+')*$';
              } else if (ind === 0) {
                regex = '^('+arrayVar+'({or}|{and})';
              } else {
                regex = regex + arrayVar + '({or}|{and})';
              }
            }
            let regexType = new RegExp(regex);
            console.log(regexType);
            let Invalidate = InlevelParentLogic.match(regex)
            if(!Invalidate){
              console.error('Invalid Logic');
              return;
            }
          }



    }catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }

validateInput();
```

Comment: Is this currently the expected output? [
  "tab1",
  "33",
  "list"
]
/^(\b(tab1|33|list)\b({or}|{and})\b(tab1|33|list)\b({or}|{and})\b(tab1|33|list)\b)*$/
Invalid Logic

Comment: I would suggest you, by using this regex pattern `/\(?[^()]*\)[^\s]+/g` ensure the `InlevelParentLogic` is a valid one . Then check whether the values of `InLevelTableList ` and `InlevelParentLogic` is equal by splitting it with `{and}{or}`